# join table's primaryID as string with sum value

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I want to join table's primaryID as string with sum value. Please see below.

Table structure

```
ID | Value
_______________
1  | 5000
_______________
2  | 6000
_______________
3  | 7000
_______________
4  | 9000
```

Query result that what I want

```
ALLID   | ALLValue
___________________
1,2,3,4 | 27000
```

How can I write sql query to produce upper result? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, for string aggregation, you can use XML logic.  Here is an example for your query:

```
select stuff((select ',' + cast(id as varchar(255)
              from structure s
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') as AllId,
       sum(value) as AllValue
from structure s;
```

Note that the outer query is an aggregation query (because of `sum(value)`) that returns only one row.  The initial subquery is not correlated with the outer query, so it will combine all `id`s into a string.

Comment: According to this query, the query executes structure table twice. For join table, is it OK for performance? Is there another way?

Comment: @zanhtet . . . I'm not sure if you have a choice in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FOR XML PATH` for concatenation

```
SELECT
    ALLID = 
        STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ID)
                FROM temp
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,''),
    AllValue = SUM(Value)
FROM temp
```

Comment: According to this query, the query executes temp table twice. For join table, is it OK for performance? Is there another way?

Comment: @zanhtet For performance you should do something like this: `SELECT SUM(Value) FROM Table` to get the sum first. Then `SELECT ID FROM Table ORDER BY ID` to get all IDs and concatenate all IDs into the single string on the client. SQL Server is poorly suited to perform such string manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
  (
     Id    INT,
     value INT
  );

INSERT INTO @T1
VALUES      (1,
             5000);

INSERT INTO @T1
VALUES      (2,
             6000);

INSERT INTO @T1
VALUES      (3,
             7000);

INSERT INTO @T1
VALUES      (4,
             9000);

SELECT stuff((SELECT ',' + cast(id AS VARCHAR(255))
              FROM   @t1 s
              FOR xml path ('')), 1, 1, '') AS AllId,
       sum(value)                           AS AllValue
FROM   @T1 s;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT substring((
          SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ID)
             FROM tbl1
           FOR XML PATH('')
    ),2,2000) as ALLID ,
    AllValue = SUM(Value)
    FROM tbl1
```

Comment: I am afraid of that there is performance problem due to this query. Because tb1 is executed twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this without using XML PATH

    CREATE TABLE #TEMP
      (
         ID    INT,
         VALUE INT
      )

    INSERT INTO #TEMP
    VALUES      (1,5000),
                (2,6000),
                (3,7000),
                (4,9000)

    DECLARE @ID    VARCHAR(MAX),
            @VALUE INT

    SET @ID = ''

    SELECT @ID = @ID + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), ID) + ','
    FROM   #TEMP

    SET @ID=(SELECT SUBSTRING(@ID, 1, LEN(@ID) - 1))
    SET @VALUE=(SELECT SUM(VALUE)
                FROM   #TEMP)

    SELECT @ID ALLID,@VALUE ALLVALUE

output: ALLID      ALLVALUE
        1,2,3,4    27000
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one.

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(50)='',@sum INT=0

SELECT @a += CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Id) + ',',
       @sum += Sum(value)
FROM   @T1
GROUP  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Id)

SELECT LEFT(@a, Len(@a) - 1) ALLID,
       @sum                  ALLValue
```